# IPV6 Still resists

Tags: 14.04, ipv6

I've got a problem in disabling IPV6 under Ubuntu 14.04
I still have UDP6 port opened even I invalidate IPV6...

Has anybody a solution?

```
$ sudo netstat -lntup
Connexions Internet actives (servers only)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale Adresse distante Etat PID/Program name
tcp 0 0 127.0.1.1:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1447/dnsmasq
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:631 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 4156/cupsd
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:631 0.0.0.0:* 1103/cups-browsed
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5353 0.0.0.0:* 969/avahi-daemon: r
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:48634 0.0.0.0:* 969/avahi-daemon: r
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:34727 0.0.0.0:* 3090/dhclient
udp 0 0 127.0.1.1:53 0.0.0.0:* 1447/dnsmasq
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:68 0.0.0.0:* 3090/dhclient
udp6 0 0 :::14820 :::* 3090/dhclient
udp6 0 0 :::5353 :::* 969/avahi-daemon: r
udp6 0 0 :::57413 :::* 969/avahi-daemon: r
```

And I did a disable:

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1

$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
1
$ sudo ufw status verbose
État*: actif
Journalisation*: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
Nouveaux profils*: skip
```

---

Thanks,
but I have solved a part of the problem in avahi-daemon:
avahi-deamon.conf 's got a "USE-IPV6" that I've put to NO...

I reboot, (BTW... it accelerates the boot!) and still remains only DHCLIENT in UDP6...
(that was not available at my first reboot, but come back at second!)

SO now the goal is to invalidate IPV6 in DHCLIENT!

maybe in dhclient-script ?... but I'm not aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling ipv6 on the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub`. Here is an example from my computer, including some other stuff on that line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 intel_pstate=enable crashkernel=384M-:128M"
```

Myself, I would suggest keeping a copy of your original grub first:

```
sudo cp grub grub.original
```

then edit grub as `sudo` (I use `nano`, you use whatever editor you like):

```
sudo nano grub
```

make the change and save the file. then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

then re-boot.